# End iterator invalidation rules

Tags: c++, iterator

Regarding [this question on iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules), it seems obvious that the spirit of the standard means, for example, that "an erase in the middle of the deque invalidates all the iterators and references to elements of the deque" also refers to the end iterator.

However, I can't find anywhere that the standard makes this explicit, and strictly speaking the end iterator is not an iterator to an *element* in the container.

Does the 2003 standard make this clear somewhere?

Comment: For example, 23.1/10: no `swap()` function invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to the elements of the containers being swapped. [ Note: The end() iterator does not refer to any element, so it may be invalidated. —end note ] ... I do not know if we can be certain that `iterator referring to an element` has been used consistently in the Standard to exclude end iterators :/

Comment: Cannot find any paragraph distinguishing end from other iterators. `end() returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value for the container`. That's all. Gee.

Comment: I don't have the 2003 standard to hand, but C++0x seems to be clear on this, e.g. "An erase operation that erases the last element of a deque invalidates only *the past-the-end
iterator* and all iterators and references to the erased elements." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Tomalak: n3242, 23.3.3.4 (probably not the most up-to-date draft)

Comment: Program defensively. Assume the `end()` iterator is invalidated along with all the others, no matter what the fine print of the standard says.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Of course. That's not what this question is about, though.

Comment: @Tomalak: Which is why I made my statement a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Matthieu: Feel free to write that as an answer. I'm satisfied with it.

Comment: why would swap invalidate the end iterator?

Comment: @Johannes: It wouldn't, and it doesn't.

Comment: @Tomalak but why does it have an explicit remark on the rule for "all swap() functions" for the end iterator? If it wouldn't matter why do they note it?

Comment: @Johannes: Ah. Well, because they're silly. :)

Comment: @Johannes: I suppose if the `end` iterator points to a sentinel value within the container, then the `end` iterators after the swap won't point to the sentinel in the "right" container, thus any sequence [it, end) would be ill-formed as `end` would not be reachable from `it`.

Comment: @Ajay: No, please do not use code formatting for things that are not code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, 23.1/10:

> no `swap()` function invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to the elements of the containers being swapped. [ Note: The `end()` iterator does not refer to any element, so it may be invalidated. —end note ]

I do not know if we can be certain that iterator referring to an element has been used consistently in the Standard to exclude end iterators :/

As said in a comment, I suppose this is to allow end iterators pointing to sentinel values within the container.

For example, a typical doubly linked `List` implementation is to create a `Node` structure, and have one `Node` by value within the `List` to act as the end node.

Comment: I'm satisfied, through this answer and through the relevant comments, that C++03 is ambiguous in this matter. Of course, in practice, we know that we should treat past-the-end iterators in the same manner as iterators to container elements; however, this answer is the answer to _this_ question.

Comment: Actually cppreference.com does talk about end() iterator's invalidation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624474/199150

Comment: Interesting; though not authoritative. I haven't followed the situation to know if requirements were tightened in newer standard versions (post C++11).