# STL iterator revalidation for end (past-the-end) iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, invalidation

See related questions on past-the-end iterator invalidation:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350454/past-the-end-iterator-invalidation-in-c11), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440392/end-iterator-invalidation-rules).

This is more a question of design, namely, **is there (in STL or elsewhere) such concept as *past-the-end iterator "revalidation"*?**

What I mean by this, and use case: suppose an algorithm needs to "tail" a container (such as a queue). It traverses the container until `end()` is reached, then pauses; independently from this, another part of the program enqueues more items in the queue. How is it possible for the algorithm to (EDIT) **efficiently** tell, "have more items been enqueued" while holding the previously past-the-end iterator (call it `tailIt`)? (this would imply it is able to check if `tailIt == container.end()` *still,* and if that is false, conclude `tailIt` is now valid and points to the first element that was inserted).

Please don't dismiss the question as "no, there isn't" - I'm looking to form judgment around how to design some logic in an idiomatic way, and have many options (in fact the iterators in question are to a hand-built data structure for which I *can* provide this property - *end() revalidation* - but I would like to judge if it is a good idea).

---

EDIT: made it clear we have the iterator `tailIt` **and** a reference to `container`. A trivial workaround for what I'm trying to do is, also remember `count` := how many items you processed, and then check is `container.size() == count` still, and if not, seek to `container[count]` and continue processing from there. This comes with many disadvantages (extra state, assumption container doesn't pop from the front (!), random-access for efficient seeking).

Comment: Trivial example. Suppose you have an `std::vector<T>` and an iterator `T* p` in the form of a raw pointer that points at the end (`= end()`). Then you expand the vector without reallocation. Would you be able to determine if the vector has been expanded if you only have the value of `p`?

Comment: Thanks - you would not, but I need to clarify something. You also have the container `c`, so you could ask is `p == c.end()` still? For the vector case and only _if there was no reallocation_, p would point to the first newly inserted element. Editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

Not in general. Here are some issues with your idea:

- Some past-the-end iterators don't "point" to the data block at all; in fact this will be true of *any* iterator except a vector iterator. So, overall, an extant end-iterator just is never going to become a valid iterator to data;
- [Iterators often become invalidated when the container changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/560648) — while this isn't always true, it also precludes a general solution that relies on dereferencing some iterator from before the mutation;
- Iterator validity is non-observable — you already need to know, before you dereference an iterator, whether or not it is valid. This is information that comes from elsewhere, usually your brain… by that I mean the developer must read the code and make a determination based on its structure and flow.

Put all these together and it is clear that the end iterator simply cannot be used this way as the iterator interface is currently designed. Iterators refer to data in a range, not to a container; it stands to reason, then, that they hold no information about a container, and if the container causes the range to change there's no entity that the iterator knows about that it can ask to find this out.

Is the described logic possible to create? Certainly! But with a different iterator interface (and support from the container). You could wrap the container in your own class type to do this. However, I advise against making things that look like standard iterators but behave differently; this will be very confusing.

Instead, encapsulate the container and provide your own wrapper function that can directly perform whatever post-enqueuement action you feel you need. You shouldn't need to watch the state of the end iterator to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

In the case for a std::queue, no there isn't (heh). Not because the iterators for a queue get invalidated once something is pushed, but because a queue doesn't have any iterators at all.

As for other iterator types, most (or any of them) of them don't require a reference to the container holder (the managing object containing all the info about the underlying data). Which is an trade-off for efficiency over flexibility. (I quickly checked the implementation of gcc's std::vector::iterator)
It is possible to write an implementation for an iterator type that keeps a reference to the holder during its lifetime, that way the iterators never have to be invalidated! (unless the holder is std::move'd)

Now to throw in my professional *opinion*, I wouldn't mind seeing a safe_iterator/flex_iterator for cases where the iterator normally would be invalidated during iterations.

Possible user interface:

```
for (auto v : make_flex_iterator(my_vector)) {
    if (some_outside_condition()) {
        // Normally the vector would be invalidated at this point
        // (only if resized, but you should always assume a resize)
        my_vector.push_back("hello world!");
    }
}
```

Literally revalidating iterators might be too complex to build for it's use case (I wouldn't know where to begin), but designing an iterator which simply never invalidates is quite trivial, with only as much overhead as a `for (size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); i++);` loop.
But with that said, I cannot assure you how well the compiler will optimize, like unrolling loops, with these iterators. I do assume it will still do quite a good job.